# Converting Glob.glob file into a pandas dataframe and append to an excel sheet

Tags: python

Here is the code I am working on to automate a daily task I do but stuck on picking up files with that change daily.

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Sales Data 2020.xlsx')

dbt = pd.read_excel('Sales Data 2020.xlsx', sheet_name='January')

test = glob.glob('January Sales 29122020.xlsx')
```

Every day I get sales data in this format January Sales 29122020. I am trying to have all the data copied and pasted over to `'Sales Data 2020.xlsx', sheet_name='January'`.

The difficulty I am having is the date of the files changes daily i.e January Sales 30122020 and there are 20 other files just like this which I need to copy and paste data to their relevant tabs. I looked at wildcards to just pick the strings in the file name as they do not change.

As for the code I am stuck because I need to convert `January Sales 29122020.xlsx` into a dataframe which I don't know how to then append/concat with the `dbt` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild card to find all files with `January Sales` then concat dataframes:

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([pd.read_excel(name, sheet_name='January') for name in glob.glob("January Sales*.xlsx")])
```